# SharePoint Web API - URL Doesn't work with hyphen ("-") in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-webservice

I have a SharePoint url which works perfectly fine this points to the production environment I am using nodejs with [getFileByName](https://gist.github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/23c185c713e04dd46caaf809f701cc19) method to consume this url -

`https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MSDS/Construction/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MSDS/Construction/ProductLabels/xxxx.pdf')/$value`

Now below is the quality server url which doesn't work at all -

`https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/qa-MSDS/Construction/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/qa-MSDS/Construction/ProductLabels/xxxx.pdf')/$value`

The difference is `qa-MSDS` instead of `MSDS`, when I use the qa web api I get below error -

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or how to solve this in a better way in node js environment?

Comment: did you try encoding the url before using inside GetFileByServerRelativeUrl ? Possible duplicate of https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214750/rest-api-error-server-relative-urls-must-start-with-spweb-serverrelativeurl

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well, with no help.

Comment: Did you try GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('ProductLabels/xxxx.pdf')

Comment: Yup I tried all permutation and combinations of `site/folder/file.extension`